# How to use conda environments in StartExternalSession?

Tags: python, external-calls, environment

I am trying to get a conda python environment to run in Mathematica under Windows.
It includes the following packages (in case you want to reproduce):

```bash
conda install python=3.7
conda install numpy
conda install netcdf4
conda install pyzmq
```

After I register the python.exe in "C:/Users/me/Miniconda3/envs/myenv/python.exe" using `RegisterExternalEvaluator` I can start and use python according to:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "1+1"]
```

> 2

This works.
However

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"]
ExternalEvaluate[session, "import numpy as np"]
```

fails with:
[image]

An error that you typically get when the environment is [not activated correctly](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html).

**How do I properly activate conda environments for python in Mathematica?**